# print from php in macosx

Tags: php, macos, printing

Does anyone know a way to print from php5 in macosx leopard similar to the windows approach using php_printer.dll?

I'm using macosx 10.5.7  and php 5.2.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only printer extension is windows-only, according to the [list of PHP extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/extensions.alphabetical.php).

Answer (score 2):

i don't know mac os well enough to give you a definate answer but here are some ideas

1. if you only want plain text can you open a filehandle to a printer and echo/print text directly to the printer.
2. create a document like a PDF file (see fpdf), and then make a system call to print that document to the default printer. i know it can be done in windows, but i am not sure about mac
3. write a native application which will do the printing and call that application from php

hope that helps